# What is the use case for Google Play Purchase.Subscription:Acknowledge?

Tags: google-play-developer-api

When should the the **acknowledge** method be used, what is the use case?
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/acknowledge

Orders do have the acknowledged (boolean) status attached to them. Is there any use to this property?

Also this request requires a body with **developerPayload**. What is this used for?

Answer (score 4):

Purchases through the Google Store have to be acknowledged in order to be considered valid.

This acknowledgement has to be done by the issuer of the app. All the examples I found in the Play Billing Library docs talk about doing it with, or via, the app itself. The "via" can be collusion with your webserver that services app requests.

However, there is also the Developer Console and its API. That's where your link comes in.  Using this route means that you don't have to rely on the app, which is much more accessible to someone changing its code, and can validate (or not) the purchase by the route

app -> Store -> Developer API -> your server -> your decision -> (n)ack

The store publishes a message about the purchase. Your server subscribes to these messages and responds to the message that is pushed to it notifying it of the purchase. Messages via this route are much harder for someone else to interfere with, and therefore more secure.

So the use case for acknowledge method appears to be

"Validating app purchases by a more secure method than from the app itself".

The acknowledgeStatus in the purchase data shows whether the purchase has already been acknowledged or not. If it hasn't it needs to be. Regular purchases need to be acknowledged within three days otherwise they are cancelled.

When you acknowledge the purchase you can attach text to the purchase via the developerPayload. The store will send this payload back to the app when the app queries purchases at some point in the future. You might find a use for this in your app, but it's not required.

Comment: Google documentation mentions none of this. Thanks for clearing it up.